# How to get json format string(extract from table)'s value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have extract a json format data from a table like this:

```
[ { id:"3",
"Date Extracted":"12/3",
Experiment:"normal"},
{ id:"2",
"Date Extracted":"12/3",
Experiment:"powder",
Notes:"" },
{ id:"1",
"Date Extracted":"12/3",
Experiment:"fine",
Notes:"" }
]
```

And I have used function like below to get only the attributes of each id like "12/3","normal", not include the name like "Date Extracted", Experiments. 
Somehow this does not work.
but I have no idea how do it exactly in details.

```
var j = JSON.parse(data);

function(){
for(name in j.property.name)
console.log(j.property.value);
}
```

Comment: [check demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6m3vrpck/) is this what you want

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you.in this case, How can I manage to ignore the name id and its attribute?

Comment: wait i will rework the demo

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6m3vrpck/1/) check demo again

Comment: Do you have suggestions on only using for loop and ignore the condition ?

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6m3vrpck/2/) something like this?

Comment: Thanks, that solves my project problem.

Comment: i will post it as answer so you can accept it and close the OP

Comment: I find another problem, how to convert this data I get from string into an object, so I can use the method you provide?

Comment: parseJSON the string it will be converted to object

Comment: I see, just use eval()

Comment: I have tried, but find parseJSON does not work on this data.

Answer (score 0):

The extracted json data had some validation issues with the property names. You could verify your jsondata via [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

So the json data should likely be:

```
var jsonData ='[{ "id":"3", "Date Extracted":"12/3","Experiment":"normal"}, { "id":"2","Date Extracted":"12/3","Experiment":"powder","Notes":"" },{ "id":"1","Date Extracted":"12/3","Experiment":"fine","Notes":"" }]';
```

Function:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
$(json).each(function(i,val){
    $.each(val,function(name,value){
        console.log(name + " : " + value);       
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I see the issue from original data, can you tell the efficient way to fix it?

Comment: Hi, per the difference in the data provided, you have to ensure that the property names should always be enclosed in quotes. Also, as I've mentioned in my proposed solution, you can always check the validity of your json data via http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "for" like that.

```
var j = JSON.parse('[{  "id": "3",  "Date Extracted": "12/3",   "Experiment": "normal"}, {  "id": "2",  "Date Extracted": "12/3",   "Experiment": "powder", "Notes": ""}, { "id": "1",  "Date Extracted": "12/3",   "Experiment": "fine",   "Notes": ""}]');for(var i=0;i<j.length;i++){
var obj = j[i];
for(var key in obj){
    var attrName = key;
    var attrValue = obj[key];
    console.log(attrValue);
}}
```

Comment: Thank you, I find a format error of my data, it does not contain certain "" in some attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
  id: "3",
  "Date Extracted": "12/3",
  Experiment: "normal"
}, {
  id: "2",
  "Date Extracted": "12/3",
  Experiment: "powder",
  Notes: ""
}, {
  id: "1",
  "Date Extracted": "12/3",
  Experiment: "fine",
  Notes: ""
}];





for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log("Date Extracted " + data[i]['Date Extracted'])//for index Date Extracted
  console.log("Experiment " + data[i]['Experiment'])//for index Experiment
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can do using for loop like this